# Leaks after fork() in child process, why?

Tags: c, macos, unix, memory-leaks, fork

Mac OSX 10.13.3. 
System leaks utility shows 4(two 2048 and two 16) leaks in next code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int st;

    if (fork())
        wait(&st);
    else
        while (1);
}
```

Why?

Comment: MacOSX libc and crt0 are rumored to leak. IIRC, even a *hello world* program is leaking. But try it by yourself (I don't use MacOSX, but Linux)

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three kinds of returned values  1) <0 means an error occurred.  2) ==0 means now in the child process.  3) >0 means now in the parent process  The posted code is failing to handle the error

Comment: when in the child process, the code will NEVER exit, so the parent will wait forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many of the C library functions will cause a 'leak' checker to flag a memory leak.

So a 'leak' checker needs to be told to NOT check the C library functions.

Other than the above, there is no memory leak in the posted code.